# Weird issue with database migration and SSL links

Tags: database, migration, ssl

I want to move my database to my another mirror server (for testing & stuff). My original one is using SSL and I am forcing it to do so.

When I migrate with DB Migrate plugin, the non-ssl server gets broken links. All links, became https. How can i fix this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a problem. Basically there were 2 options that forced my permalinks to https:

1. Settings > General: change the site url from https to http.
2. SEO by Yoast plugin, under section permalinks needed to change Canonical Settings to force HTTP.